# Find youtube url in json file with ruby

Tags: ruby, string, search, grep

For testing purpose my json file (test.json) consists of only the string I want to find:

```
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBIZF3sDFTI"
```

Somehow I cannot find the string in file with this ruby code:

```
if not File.foreach("test.json").grep(/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBIZF3sDFTI/).any?

  puts("string not in file")
end
```

Output: "string not in file"

But the string is in the file.

Searching for other strings works fine, so it must be a problem with this particular string.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: So, for testing purpose your `json` file is not a `json` file?

Comment: With that Ruby code, I get a `SyntaxError`

Comment: if you don't mind using a library, check out https://github.com/talyssonoc/CommonRegexRuby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problems

Your regex pattern isn't valid, because it's got too many forward slashes in it. Specifically:

```
/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBIZF3sDFTI/
```

is *not* a valid regular expression. Your String is also not a valid a JSON object.

### Solution

You need to escape special regular expression characters like `/` and `?` before trying to use your pattern. For example, you could call [Regexp#escape](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) on the String like so:

```
Regexp.escape 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBIZF3sDFTI'
#=> "https://www\\.youtube\\.com/watch\\?v=hBIZF3sDFTI"
```

Then, assuming you have a valid JSON object, you could match the expression as follows:

```
require 'json'

str  = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBIZF3sDFTI'
json = str.to_json
#=> "\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBIZF3sDFTI\""

pattern = Regexp.escape str
json.match pattern
#=> #<MatchData "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBIZF3sDFTI">
```

Comment: _"isn't valid, because it's got too many forward slashes"_ – how many slashes are okay? ;-)

Comment: @Stefan I know you're being humorous, but for the benefit of future visitors, the standard regex literals (e.g. not useing `%r`) can have *zero* unescaped forward slashes within the expression. I suppose the OP could have solved part of the problem with `%r{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBIZF3sDFTI}`, but that just kicks the can down the road since any literal constructor might need to be escaped in some future string.

Comment: And even in `%r` you have to escape `.` and `?`, so `Regexp.escape` is the way to go. However, note that it returns a _string_. You probably want `pattern` to be a regexp. (your example works nonetheless because `match` converts it, but that might not be obvious)